# Unable to Resolve Host Name of SOAP Service

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I've added a service reference to a third party API that I have no control over.

The endpoint looks like this (URL masked) and the service is available from this address as I can call it using SOAPUI:

```
<endpoint address="https://some-api.domain.com/service-name/do-something"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="FindPolicyPortSoap11"
    contract="FindPolicy.FindPolicyPort" name="FindPolicyPortSoap11" />
```

When calling the service, I get the error `The remote name could not be resolved: 'some-api.domain.com` which is technically correct as `some-api.domain.com` will produce a 404 whereas `some-api.domain.com/service-name/do-something` works as expected.

What can I do to get this working?

Comment: The address in your endpoint should just be the root of the service i.e. `http://www.example.com/exampleservice.svc` in your example: `https://some-api.domain.com/service-name` The method would be invoked in your code.

Comment: @Popo The address that I've used is 100% correct.

Comment: like popo said, you normally would add the filename as well, for example: /service.svc. is your binding contract correctly setup? the configuration should have: <security mode="Transport" /> for an HTTPS address.

Comment: have you tried setting the defaultproxy to true in system.net tag? [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/network/defaultproxy-element-network-settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/network/defaultproxy-element-network-settings)

Comment: try to use IP address instead of domain name since domain host only be accessed within appropriate domain.

Comment: @mahlatse - Looks like you're spot on, I needed to set the defaultProxy setting to true which now allows the address to be resolved! I have other issues but I'll sort them. Pop this comment into an answer and I'll accept! Thanks again.

Comment: @Gareth Does it work via WCF? I am not clear if you are saying it does or doesn't, or if it only works via SOAPUI. If only works via SOAPUI and if the address is correct, then it is not the issue, there is nothing wrong with the endpoint node, please provide more information such as your binding, behavior, and the code used to make the API call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the defaultproxy to true in system.net tag?

Accordig to MSDN

> If the defaultProxy element is empty, the proxy settings from Internet
>   Explorer will be used. This behavior is different from version 1.1 of
>   the .NET Framework.

```
<defaultProxy  
        enabled="true|false"  
        useDefaultCredentials="true|false">  
           <bypasslist> … </bypasslist>  
           <proxy> … </proxy>  
           <module> … </module>  
      </defaultProxy>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/network/defaultproxy-element-network-settings

Answer (score 0):

This error related to resolving some-api.domain.com to specific ip address 
I would try using nslookup or 
http://www.kloth.net/services/nslookup.php
Another option is to add this domain to your hosts file just to test it

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your answer.

Comment: The error you got is not related to full or partial url path only to the fact it can't resolve host name